# $\int_{(0,\infty)}\frac{1}{x}\sin (\frac{\pi}{2}x) d\mu$ for certain measure $\mu$.

Tags: integration, measure-theory

I have to check if $f(x):=\frac{1}{x}\sin (\frac{\pi}{2}x)$ is integrable in $(0,\infty)$ , with the measure $\mu$ where $\mu(A)=\mathrm{card}(A\cap\mathbb{N})$ if $A\cap\mathbb{N}$ is finite and $\mu(A)=\infty$ if $A\cap\mathbb{N}$ is not finite.

I have tried to write Taylor series expansion for sine at $x = 0$, but I cannot use any result to pull the summation out of the integral.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You don't need the Taylor series. If $g$ is $\mu$-integrable, what is $\int_{(0,\infty)} g\,d\mu$?

Comment: Can you do the integral from $1$ to $2$ at least?  Then you won't be confused by Taylor series...

Comment: $\mu (X-\mathbb{N})=0$, so that integral is $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sin(\frac{n\pi}{2})$, isn't it?

Comment: Is that serie convergent?

Comment: Work out $\sin ({ n \pi \over 2})$ explicitly...

Comment: Also, remember that you need to check that $\int |f| d \mu$ is finite...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\mu((0,\infty)-\mathbb{N})=0$, so $\int_{(0,\infty)}\frac{1}{x}\sin (\frac{\pi}{2}x) d\mu=\int_{\mathbb{N}}\frac{1}{x}\sin (\frac{\pi}{2}x) d\mu=\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sin (\frac{\pi}{2}n)=\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}}{2n+1}=\arctan(1)=\pi/4.$

According to this, $f$ is integrable.